# Selenium - Updating table columns if altered

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I received a table and was able to get and validate the data (whether the email is ACTUALLY an email and so forth). We want to validate the data that is displayed on the front end with the backend. There was a table (I had seen the table- the first column was name and then email , phone number, company , country and the date).

Now, the person on the front-end, switched up the columns. I had seen the table before and therefore I knew the order I would receive my information. I will have to change the code everytime a small change is made on the front end. FYI, the table headers are defined with "data-name" so I will be able to use it if your solution involves something w/ table headers. My code is posted below:

```
    public static void getTableContents(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //TODO Replace this w. until it find command
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log("TABLE CONTENTS VERIFICATION");
    //Get the table contents 
    WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.className(TABLE_RESPONSE));
    //Click on a button to switch into the desired column
    WebElement switchColumn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".switchColumn img.pull-right"));
    switchColumn.click();

    // We do not want the first two contents as they represent default or error case. 
    List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[position()>2]"));

    int i=1;
    for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
    {
        List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
        int j=1;
        for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
        {
            String check = tdElement.getText();


            if(j==1) {
                if(isValidName(check))
                    passed("Name Test : " );
                else{
                    log(check + " is not a valid name");
                }
            }
            if(j==2) {
                if(isValidEmail(check))
                {   passed("Email address Test : ");

                }
                else
                    log(check + " is not a valid email"); 
            }
            if(j==3) {
                if(isValidNumber(check))
                    passed("Valid Number test : ");
                else
                    log(check + " is not a valid number");
            }
            if(j==6){
                if(isValidIccid(check))
                    passed("Valid Iccid test : ");
                else
                    log(check+ " is not a valid Iccid");
            }
            if(j==4){
                //Blank (for a while)
            }
            if(j==5){
                if(isValidCountry(check))

                    passed("Valid country test : ");
                else
                    log(check+ " is not a valid country");
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }

}
```

Is there any quick way of changing this code to my requirements? I can't keep changing the numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6) all the times. I am just looking for clever ways to UPDATE my code rather than CHANGE my code completely.

Any help/tip is greatly appreciated.EDIT: Also, I will be changing my if/else statements to switch cases so it is easier to understand. But as of now, I got a great problem cause I might have to change my entire code so please do not mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table has the table headers with classes like:

`data-Name
 data-Email`

then you can use this in the code as follows:

```
// We do not want the first two contents as they represent default or error case. 
List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[position()>2]"));

int i=1;
for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
{
    List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
    int j=1;
    for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
    {
        String check = tdElement.getText();
        String header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//tr/th[" + j + "]")).getAttribute("class");

        if(header.equals("data-Name")) {
            if(isValidName(check))
                passed("Name Test : " );
            else{
                log(check + " is not a valid name");
            }
        }
        if(header.equals("data-Email")) {
            if(isValidEmail(check))
            {   passed("Email address Test : ");

            }
            else
                log(check + " is not a valid email"); 
        }
        //... and so on

     }
  }
```

You might need to change this line to reflect the correct way for you to identify the table headers:

```
String header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody//tr/th[" + j + "]")).getAttribute("class");
```

but the point is to use the "j" counter to track the column that you are on and check the class name of the header for that column. The order of the columns should no longer matter if you identify them this way.